# Saving a the contents of string in a xml and reading the xml file again

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a HTML page which contains users data and the data is stored in  tags, I have selected particular div tags and saved as a string using java servlet now I need to save those strings in a xml file. I am newbie to java I was able to generate a xml file and add some contents to it, it was experimental project.

In the real time I have the above scenario and once I store the store those strings in a xml I need to read that back and present it as HTML to the broswers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Java Architecture for XML Binding` (JAXB).
You can create simple POJO file with all the properties of User.

Reading and writing is done on the back hand by JAVA.

A very simple JAXB tutorial is available [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JAXB/article.html).

You can find many other useful articles on web.